# How to run multiple validator instances on localhost to not falling behind

Tags: validator, solana-test-validator, development, local-cluster

I try to run solana validator at my laptop. I would like to start with the test validator and join two or three solana validators. I follow the guide from here
https://github.com/mvines/validator-Identity-transition-demo

```
solana-test-validator --reset --slots-per-epoch 32 --ledger /tmp/test-ledger
```

I start with the `solana-test-validator` but while I start the other `solana-validator` I usually experience issues on not having the follower validators to reach the tip of the blockchain slots.

```
solana-validator --entrypoint 127.0.0.1:1024 \
    --identity staked-identity.json \
    --vote-account `solana-keygen pubkey vote-account.json` \
    --check-vote-account http://localhost:8899 \
    --authorized-voter staked-identity.json \
    --ledger /tmp/validator --allow-private-addr --rpc-port 10999 \
    --no-os-network-limits-test \
    --limit-ledger-size 500000000 \
    --full-rpc-api
```

When waiting on validator to follow the blockchain defined by genesis of the test validator it just starts to fall behind.

```
solana catchup --our-localhost 10999
# ...our node is falling behind at ~2.4 slots/second...
```

[image]

From what I can read at other places
https://www.reddit.com/r/solana/comments/pfp6ut/running_a_solana_validator_lessons_tips/
I assume the trouble could be with the HW of my laptop that is not capable to run multiple Solana instances in the good pace.

Is there some tuning option for the validator or setup somehow the genesis configuration to make the validator to consume less CPU/memory? It's a testing environment and I'm fine to have things to works slower or with less security.

I tried to change the `--ticks-per-slot` which makes slower slots to be obtained but no change in the CPU demands.

Would you have some tips for me, please?

---

EDIT: I found (https://github.com/mvines/validator-Identity-transition-demo/issues/1) that the test validator runs the sleepy PoH that should make the validators running with much less demands than the real validtors. Just it still does not solve my trouble of having the test validators falling behind.

Comment: you're going to need to provide logs from one of the secondary validators. they'll probably be too large to post here, so publish them elsewhere and add a link.

Comment: @trent.sol thanks. I returned to this and with some experiments I found that for example running the test validator with `--slots-per-epoch 100` makes my laptop capable to catch the second validator with pace of the "test cluster". When running with `--slots-per-epoch 750` then only first validator is capable to catch the cluster, the second one is not capable. I'm not sure what part of the validator log is the important one and the logs are pretty long so packed them to https://mega.nz/file/sxoHAKiQ#fC3icI7yTfko_5rRWpRHhlAOC1T5bEKYxZ3_O6blywo (validator 1 catches, validator 2 falls behind).